# Can't get data from rapidapi in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, api, dart, rapidapi

I can't fetch data from rapidapi.The console said

**E/LB      (12826): fail to open file: No such file or directory**

**I/_complete_guid(12826): ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=655 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000**

I try everything I can but still not working.

```
class APIService {
  final String uri =
      'https://billboard2.p.rapidapi.com/billboard_global_200?date=2020-09-19';

  Future<List<Song>> getGlobal200() async {
    Response rs = await get(Uri.parse(uri), headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-key": '----',
      "x-rapidapi-host": "billboard2.p.rapidapi.com",
    });

    if (rs.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(rs.body);

      List<dynamic> body = json['songs'];

      List<Song> songs =
          body.map((dynamic item) => Song.fromJson(item)).toList();

      return songs;
    } else {
      throw ('Cant\'t get the Songs');
    }
  }
}
```

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(chartApp());
}
class chartApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: _HomeView(),
    );
  }
}

class _HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  _HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  __HomeViewState createState() => __HomeViewState();
}

class __HomeViewState extends State<_HomeView> {
  APIService client = APIService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('ChartApp'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: client.getGlobal200(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Song>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: Text('Success'),
              );
            } 
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you identify the line throwing that error?

Comment: There is no error but I think something is wrong in api calling method.